# FirebaseMessaging getToken doesn't work on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter

On iOS, the getToken function from FirebaseMessaging doesn't works, no excepetions are thrown.

```
try {
  final firebase = FirebaseMessaging();
  final deviceToken = await firebase.getToken();
  //DO SOMETHING
} catch (e) {
  //DO SOMETHING ELSE
}
```

The execution stops on the getToken. I generated Podfile code and builded without any errors.
I don't know how to better explain this error. Anyone had the same issue?

Comment: Did you try printing the content of deviceToken  ??

Comment: My code doesn't pass the getToken function, so I can't even print the content of deviceToken or anything else after that. It should at least throw me an exception, but there's none.

Comment: did you get any success with this? I have been facing the exact similar situation here

Comment: No I didn't. Had to freeze the project.

Answer (score 1):

I''m sure this should work or should at least give you the reason(Tested/verified) :

Replace your :

```
final deviceToken = await firebase.getToken();
```

with :

`firebase.getToken().then((String deviceToken) { //Anything you may wanna do.. }).catchError((e) { print('Something went wrong : $e'); });`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for the sake of anyone reading this in the future. I came across this same problem and it took me days to figure out what the problem really was. It turns out that you need to call `requestPermission()` on iOS device before you call `getToken()` method. So for the above question the code should look like:

```
... 
final firebase = FirebaseMessaging();
await firebase.requestPermission();
final deviceToken = await firebase.getToken();
...
```

There is no official documentation for this. But this is what solved my problem.